# add data to a Laravel collection

Tags: laravel, collections

I'm trying to use Laravel collections for a simple case. I'm building a collection of furniture items and I would like to amend the item lines with additional information afterwards :

```
$collection = collect([
    ['name' => 'Desk', 'color' => 'Black'],
    ['name' => 'Chair', 'color' => 'Black'],
    ['name' => 'Bookcase', 'color' => 'Red'],
]);
```

I would like to add a 'stock_value' field for some items, based on the item key 'name' (for instance). In the end, I would like the collection to become something like :

```
['name' => 'Desk', 'color' => 'Black', 'stock_value' => 4],
['name' => 'Chair', 'color' => 'Black'],
['name' => 'Bookcase', 'color' => 'Red', 'stock_value' => 9]
```

I don't know how to achieve that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$stockValue = 9;

return $collection->transform(function ($array) use ($stockValue) {
        if ($array['name'] === 'Desk') {
            $array['stock_value'] = $stockValue;
        }

        return $array;
    });
```

You may use `transform` to modify your collection.

Comment: Oh OK, looks nice. And how can I pass variables inside the closure? for the stock value for instance ? I'd like the 9 to be a variable.

Comment: you can add your variables into `use` statement - answer updated